# SAW Filter input power restriction

Tags: rf, filter, wireless

I have front end module (915MHz freq band) in circuit Which is having 30dBm output power. Between This FEM and antenna I have to insert filtering circuit.
I came across few SAW filters from Murata, Kyocera, Abracon but all those are having having max. 15dBm input power specs.
So let me know how this can be taken care .

Thanks

Comment: What precisely are your filtering requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you don't use a SAW filter at those power levels (They are a tool for receivers and power levels generally lower then 10dBm.

915MHz is high enough that printing some sort of interdigital filter right on the board may work, or print the inductors and use lumped element caps? If you want really sharp skirts cavity designs are possible but can be a bit of a manufacturing pain.

You might find something off the shelf from someone like minicircuits, but usually this sort of thing is just something you design in one of the standard LC topologies, or as a microwave filter.